# Chance of random generated string of being in a set with strings

Tags: probability, combinatorics, probability-theory

Given a finite set of **m strings** with **length n**. Each position of the string can be one of **k possibilites** for a character.

If I now generate such a string what is the chance of it being in the set?

Comment: Do you know how to find the total number $T$ of possible strings? Then the answer will be $m/T$.

Comment: k^n I would say, right? @EthanBolker

Comment: Yes, right. You should either answer your own question here and accept the answer, or delete it, so that it does not remain on the queue.

Comment: Another question though if I may @EthanBolker : what if each of the characters in the string has a probability assigned to it. Like lets say I have a software that scans a string and gives back the string with each character having a probability assigned to it measuring the chance it was scanned correctly. This uncertainty would change the probability of the string being in the set. How do I put this uncertainty for each character to the calculation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The probability is $m/k^n$.

Answering the harder question asked in the comment:

> What if each of the characters in the string has a probability
>   assigned to it. Like lets say I have a software that scans a string
>   and gives back the string with each character having a probability
>   assigned to it measuring the chance it was scanned correctly. This
>   uncertainty would change the probability of the string being in the
>   set. How do I put this uncertainty for each character to the
>   calculation?

Or, rather, not answering, since there is no easy answer.

If the probability of a bad character scan is $p$, independent from character to character, then it's not hard to calculate the probability that $j$ of the $n$ characters are wrong. But without more information about the set $V$ of valid strings you are looking for you can't calculate the probability that the misread string is in $V$. That will depend on how often random changes of strings in $V$ stay in $V$.

Some of what you are asking about may be addressed by [coding theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coding_theory).

You may get more help if you submit a new question with much more context about your use case.

Comment: I see, but the strings in V dont have probabilities assigned to them since these are fixed, so there are no random changes in V.

Comment: Yes, the strings in $V$, are fixed, not random,  but you need to know the probability that a random change in a string in $V$ keeps it in $V$, In coding theory you design $V$ so that probability is small. If $V$ is a set of real words you want to recognize the problem is nastier.

Comment: Ok Thanks. I think I understand it but not 100% sure. Anthing in coding theory you can guide me to, where the problem is similar? Anyway gonna mark this as an answer :)

Comment: Roughly speaking, coding theory chooses a set $V$ of code words that are far apart when subject to random changes. That means a word that's not in $V$ can be close to just one word in $V$, so correctly "decoded" in spite of a few errors. Whether this is similar to your problem depends on the details of your problem - which is why I suggested you might want to ask a more detailed question, with more context.